# Web service return empty on WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 ESB to access our services. We have developed services on Application Server and we could access them via using ESB Proxy services. However sometimes ESB returns empty values to our clients. If i call AS directly i could see the response. When ESB starts to turn empty value it is effecting all of our servises on ESB. We could not find how could we fix the problem. When we restart the ESB server everything starting to work again.

We are using WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 and WSO2 AS 5.0.2

Thanks,

Ps: I am executing this script to look at web service response. But web service response is empty.
curl -d @request.xml -H "Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8" "http://esbhostname.com:8280/services/Report" > response.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have noticed such an issue in passthrough transport..but it is really hard to reproduce..What we noticed is, wso2esb 4.6.0 drops POST message body sometimes..not sure what is the root cause or in which situation it happened..we will try to fix that issue soon once we are able to reproduce it..
This issuse happens with passthrough transport..If you dont really need passthrough transport, you can switch to nio tarnsport. Edit the axis2.xml transport sender/receiver for nio transport.

Comment: Thank you Ratha, I will try NIO transport for ESB. However We could also see the same exception on load balancer too. Do you think i could use same workaround for LB too.

Comment: sure, the ELB also uses the passthrough transport..so, might experience same issue there...if we fix teh issue..that will be available in esb+elb+apim

Comment: Hi Ratha, Changing the passthroug transport to nio transport has solved my problem. Is there any open bug on wso2 or axis2 about this problem. I would like to follow it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Starting from ESB 4.6.0, the default transport is passthru. You could try the same scenario with NHTTP transport. Follow the steps below to use NHTTP instead of passthru.

- Open ESB_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml
- Under `<Axis2Config>`, you will find will find a xml tag called
  `<ConfigurationFile`>. It currently points to
  `${carbon.home}/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml`.
- Modify that location to this -

  `${carbon.home}/repository/conf/axis2/axis2_nhttp.xml`
- Restart the WSO2 ESB

Comment: Hi, I'm using wso2 esb 4.8.1 and I have the empty response problem when I use the callout mediator. If I try to call an unreachable host (wrong endpoint host for example), the callout mediator does not raise any fault, the default fault sequence is not executed. No response is sent back to the client. How to handle socket timeout in callout mediator? The same test works fine with send mediator.

Comment: I solved by using in carbon.xml the axis2_nhttp.xml and adding this porperty to the nhttp.properties : http.socket.timeout.receiver=90000 (the socket timeout in my callout is still 60 seconds, but now the caller can get the fault)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what happens based on your description... but I can suggest you to use tcpmon in between the AS and ESB... Then you can get some idea what went wrong...

Tcpmon can be found at ESB_HOME/bin/ . Route the proxy to tcpmon and from tcpmon  route to AS. then based on the request and response you can get a better idea...

Thanks,

Mohan

Comment: Thank you for the response Mohan, When i get empty response from ESB i am calling web service from AS directly and i could see the response. So i think somehow ESB overriding AS response and return empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue has been reported by one of our client. In that scenario, user has observed that after sending around 3 or 4 requests to the REST service from ESB, it starts to stop sending messages from ESB to the back end REST service. In this case, ESB just suspend the endpoint and stop sending requests to REST service after some time. If you can put a tcpmon between ESB and AS, you can verify that whether this is the case. Again, this also happens only with default Pass-Through Transport.

Comment: Hi Chanaka, I am using the ESB 4.8.1 and i have the behavior you have mentioned. ESB simply does not forward any traffic to Back End and once ESB get in to this situation, it does not seem to recover as well. What is the best solution without switching back to NHTTP for this? Can WSO2 make the patch available publicly since this make the ESB and API Manager pretty much unusable?