# Error while sending message to message broker from ESB's proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am currently trying to do the example presented in this Link:http://wso2.org/library/articles/2013/03/configuring-wso2-esb-wso2-message-broker. I am trying to post message to topic of message broker but everytime i access my proxy server and try to send message from esb proxy, i get this error. I dont know what went wrong. Till morning this was working. My error is:

```
[2013-04-30 16:40:27,516] ERROR - ClientUtils The system cannot infer the transport information from the jms:/myTopic?&t
ransport.jms.DestinationType=topic URL.
[2013-04-30 16:40:27,526] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the jms:/myTopic?&transport.jms.Desti
nationType=topic URL.
        at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:81)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.prepareMessageContext(OperationClient.java:288)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:249)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:456)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:57)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:316)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:329)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:175)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:476)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:296)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[2013-04-30 16:40:27,526]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : endpoint_1afcbfaeb203878a99e989ab5fa10f9e1385b22f66654582 w
ill be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2013-04-30 16:40:27,526]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : endpoint_1afcbfaeb203878a99e989ab5fa10f9e1385b22
f66654582 - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Tue Apr 30 16:40:57 IST 2013
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange. You say it was working until today morning. But according to the exception, JMS transport sender is not enabled in your ESB's axis2.xml. Please check whether it is enabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot Amila sir. You saved me.I was working on security implementation on proxy service so i had refrenced to nHTTP axis2 instead of axis2.xml. SO i was getting this error.Thank you very very much sir

Comment: Amila sir, Can you look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279353/client-giving-error-when-invoking-a-secured-web-service